# Listbox Multiselect add to next available blank cell & remove from original range

Tags: vba, excel

Hopefully someone can help me? I have 2 list boxes RndAdd1 & RndEdit1. I want to be able to multi select items in RndAdd1 and then click Button1 and it loops through selected items and one at a time adds them to the new range (first blank cell) until all items added. Then remove all the values just added from the original range. (basically move from Column A to Column B for Monday, Column C to D for Tuesday and so on)

I also have another variable set (which day of the week) I have the following code I was going to place on the button then nest a series of if/Elseif statements.

The trouble I'm having currently is that it posts the first value in the first blank cell, then the 2nd value overwrites the first value and so on until only the final value is now visible in the new range. This is probably a simple fix and I'm just not thinking of it in the correct way!

```
Dim lItem As Long
For lItem = 0 To RndAdd1.ListCount - 1
    If RndAdd1.Selected(lItem) = True Then
        If ComboBox1.Value = "Monday" Then
            Sheets("Setup").Range("B65536").End(xlUp)(0, 1) = RndAdd1.List(lItem)
            RndAdd1.Selected(lItem) = False
        End If
    End If
Next

RndAdd1.Clear
RndEdit1.Clear
ComboBox1.Clear
ComboBox1.List = Array("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday")

ComboBox1.Value = "Monday"

'Tuesday Repeat Code but with different range to take round numbers from
```

Comment: is your code actually compiling? there seem to be missing an `End If` or the likes

Comment: @user3598756 I added in the extra elseif on the fly as that is the way it will work and I missed the final end if but I do know the rest of the code does what I described just it doesn't quite work how it is intended.

Comment: I think you may just need `Sheets("Setup").Range("B65536").End(xlUp)(2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm on my phone so cannot post code buy maybe this can help you:

```
Dim TargetRange as range 

Set TargetRange = thisworkbook.sheets(1).range("A1")  'or whereever you want it

Do until IsEmpty(TargetRange.value)
Set targetrange = targetrange.offset(1,0)
Loop

TargetRange.value = "your value here"
```

This loops down until it finds an empty cell

Hope it helps

Comment: Some slight adjustment but this works perfectly Thanks :-) @Benoit Ranque

Comment: @Alan Treanor if performance is an issue you might want to use the code provided in the other answer. I'm out of my dept here, but I believe it is faster since it uses built in excel functions. My code sets a range object for every iteration of the loop, so I'm pretty sure it's inefficient. Again I'm a beginner so not sure.

Comment: Thanks, this particular code is only designed to be run once a week as a setup platform for the following week and will only look down a list of about 200 numbers! Thanks 

Answer (score 0):

substitute

```
Sheets("Setup").Range("B65536").End(xlUp)(0, 1) = RndAdd1.List(lItem)
```

with

```
With Sheets("Setup")
    .Range(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1) = RndAdd1.List(lItem)
End With
```

Comment: app defined or object defined error when using this code.

Comment: I have it sorted now though another code above helped. Thanks for the help :-)

.Range(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1) = RndAdd1.List(lItem)

Comment: if your original code didn't throw any error then that _only_ revision wouldn't either.